# Paypal Recuring Payment with Paypal Express

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal

I want to integrate paypal recurring plans and subscription in my rails project. But I could not find good documentation and the blog or videos found are too old. 
The gem "paypal_express" still uses username and password for authentication. Shouldn't it be with OAuth2.

Please suggest any gem or good tutorials to start with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `gem 'paypal-sdk-rest'` for creating Paypal subscription plans and recursive payments.
As it does not include the subscription part I have added it by myself. 
https://gist.github.com/jbmyid/16c70067ea3f5cea7d2b

Answer (score 0):

[paypal express gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/paypal-express) is built for PayPal's classic API, express checkout, that authenticates with ID and password. The new generation of SDK (REST SDK) uses OAuth2.

Express Checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/

REST: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

I fing [this](http://www.tommyblue.it/2013/07/03/paypal-express-checkout-with-ruby-on-rails-and-paypal-sdk-merchant/) as best blog for paypal integration. I have used this for integrating pay-pal integration which is working fine